# Wire, Use Injector outside main package

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I am pretty new to Go and I was experimenting with the DI as provided by Wire.

In my usecase I am using wire to inject the config where I require it. I had followed along their guide on doing this.

```
main.go: [package main]

func main() {
    Init(InitAndGetConfig())
}

wire.go [package main]

func InitAndGetConfig() *config.SomeConfig {
    wire.Build(config.GetP, config.Load)
    return &config.SomeConfig{}
}
```

This works well, I can load the config from main once I get the `wire_gen.go`

Now in a separate package `[package sample]` when I try to do `InitAndGetConfig()` I am getting an `Unresolved reference 'InitAndGetConfig'`

What do I miss here? I come from a Java/Koin background and my understanding is that I should be able to DI at any place.

Comment: You can't use a function defined in `main` from another package You should put your commonly used functions in a separate package (eg: `utils`). You can then call `utils.InitAndGetConfig()` from other packages. I recommend you take the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I was naive enough to follow the official guide and take the word for it, I changed the package and its working great! Thanks again for referencing the tutorial, I will not go through it!

Comment: I meant, I will now* go through it!